# GetDpiForMonitor with Delphi 7 for per-monitor DPI awareness

Tags: winapi, delphi-7

The WinAPI function GetDpiForMonitor doesn't have a header translation for Delphi 7 and searching the internet I could not find one.

If anyone has sample code showing how to use this WinAPI function from Delphi 7, that would help greatly.

Comment: This is an exceptionally simple function to translate. Have you made an attempt? If it's too hard for you, there is the jedi project of header translations.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I posted this as an internet search did not resolve clear Delphi code and since others may also need it, I posted this question so future searches will result with an answer. I did look into the JEDI API library and it doesn't contain any reference to "GetDpiForMonitor".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to dynamically load the DLL and call the function in Delphi 7:

```
Type
  TMONITOR_DPI_TYPE = (
    MDT_EFFECTIVE_DPI {= 0},
    MDT_ANGULAR_DPI   {= 1},
    MDT_RAW_DPI       {= 2},
    MDT_DEFAULT       {= MDT_EFFECTIVE_DPI });

var
  dpiX              : UINT;
  dpiY              : UINT;
  ErrCode           : HResult;
  hShcore           : THandle;
  GetDpiForMonitor  : function(monitor: HMONITOR; dpiType: TMONITOR_DPI_TYPE; var dpi, dpiY: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;

begin
  hShcore := GetModuleHandle('Shcore');
  If hShcore <> 0 then GetDpiForMonitor := GetProcAddress(hShcore,'GetDpiForMonitor');
  If @GetDpiForMonitor <> nil then 
    ErrCode := GetDpiForMonitor(Monitor.Handle,MDT_EFFECTIVE_DPI,dpiX,dpiY);
end;
```

Comment: That's good. Well done. You should ensure that the enum is declared with MINENUMSIZE of 4

Comment: My other comment is that you should use LoadLibrary to obtain the module handle. It might lot be loaded. Or, worse, it might be unloaded before you call the function.