# Get screen's physical ppi with Delphi 10.4 in windows 10

Tags: delphi, screen, ppi

I am developing an application that draws on screen. I want to know the physical ppi of the screen to draw eg. a rectangle 2x2 inches to its actual size, so the user be able to measure it on screen as 2x2 inches.

Comment: Although not directly answering your question as it's for an older version of Delphi. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615108/getdpiformonitor-with-delphi-7-for-per-monitor-dpi-awareness

Comment: The Windows API of `GetDpiForMonitor` called with `MDT_RAW_DPI` to learn the Dots Per Inch.

Comment: @RobertLove,  GetDpiForMonitor is unknown. In which unit is included, please ?

Comment: @JimPapas it is declared in the `Winapi.ShellScaling` unit

Comment: @JimPapas: The IDE can tell you this, if you use Search->Find in folders, point it to the VCL source directory tree, and tell it to include sub-folders. I've used it for decades to locate things both in the Delphi source folders and third-party source. And if it's not located anywhere, you can define it yourself based on the MS documentation, which you can easily find using your favorite internet search engine.

Comment: @KenWhite, although I had used this search in the past, it didn't cross my mind this time. Thank you for the reminder

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this function to get PPI of the primary screen on FireMonkey:

```
uses FMX.Platform

...

function GetScreenPPI: Double;
var
  ScreenService: IFMXScreenService;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXScreenService, ScreenService) then
    Result := ScreenService.GetScreenScale() * 96
  else
    Result := 96; // Fallback to default of 96
end;
```